Why PyInstaller doesn't see modules?
I'm trying to reproduce the example code of pySiril and compile it all into an exe file so that I can freely distribute my scripts for processing astrophotography.
from pysiril.siril import Siril
from pysiril.wrapper import Wrapper
from pysiril.addons import Addons

app = Siril(siril_exe='D:\\Programs\\Siril\\bin\\siril-cli.exe')  # Starts pySiril
cmd = Wrapper(app)  # Starts the command wrapper

help(Siril)  # Get help on Siril functions
help(Wrapper)  # Get help on all Wrapper functions
help(Addons)  # Get help on all Addons functions

cmd.help()  # Lists of all commands
cmd.help('bgnoise')  # Get help for bgnoise command

del app

pyinstaller -F main.py

However, when starting the exe, an error appears that the module was not found:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pysiril.siril import Siril
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "pysiril\siril.py", line 32, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'changelog'
[1824] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

It requires all existing imports in siril.py:
import changelog
import LogMsg
import PipeReader
import PipeWriter
import ThreadSiril
import tools

I can install via pip changelog, but what about the rest?
They are nowhere to be found... but why does everything work fine without the exe?
Github code

Note that [mre] requirements call for everything needed to reproduce the problem to be included in the text of the question itself. Links are fine for supplemental content, but a question needs to be answerable, and answers need to be testable, without them (so answers still make sense even if links in the question break or have contents behind them change or the future).

As for "why does everything work fine without [pyinstaller]?", I'd suggest investigating a bit in a REPL. After successfully running import LogMsg in a REPL, look at LogMsg.__file__ and see where it came from; inspect sys.path and compare it against its original state; etc. If you learn that you need to tell pyinstaller to look in unusual sys.path locations (f/e), then there you are.

As a starting point into things that are weird here, though -- as a rule, virtualenvs should never be checked in as code.

Beyond that, it looks to me like this should be import pysiril.lib.LogMsg as LogMsg, not import LogMsg, and likewise for the others. If pysiril is patching sys.path to add its lib directory as a top-level entry... well, short form is that it shouldn't, and its author(s) should be ashamed of themselves for publishing code with that kind of ugly hack.

@CharlesDuffy, Isn't a github repository, which even has a ready-made virtual environment, an ideal example? Or is it better to clutter the post with a huge number of lines that are necessary to reproduce the problem?

The problem with virtualenvs in general is that they aren't portable: There's no guarantee that a virtualenv made on Person A's machine will work on Person B's, and in practice they very often don't. That's why it's common to package code that when run creates and populates a new virtualenv on the recipient's system (requirements.txt, setup.py, pyproject.toml &c can all be useful towards this end), whereas packaging a virtualenv itself is Not Done.

This is a bug in pysiril, even if its author doesn't think of it as one: where that library should be referring to contents of the pysiril.lib directory as pysiril.lib.<thing>, it's instead setting up sys.path to include the lib directory and trying to just import <thing>.
That's malpractice (and pyinstaller rightly doesn't support it). The appropriate fix is to modify pysiril to refer to items it vendors under the namespace, or (where they exist as external packages) to properly register them as dependencies (with install locations &c) in setup.py or similar.
That is to say, code that currently runs import LogMsg should instead run import pysiril.lib.LogMsg as LogMsg.

When I changed all the imports to what you specified, it started working, however in the example, when I run through the IDE, then help(Siril) and the rest of the commands work correctly. It is enough to pack them into the exe and it will start writing an error that the name help is not defined.

@CharlesDuffy - Hi Charles, bet you could help me with this problem! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78704041/how-do-i-redirect-socats-stdin-and-stdout-to-its-parent-process-which-is-a-bash/78704349#78704349   Hope you're doing well!

You've landed on a solution that is pretty much what I'd do myself :)
