How do I redirect socat's stdin and stdout to its parent process which is a bash script?
What I want to do SHOULD be fairly straight forward but a whole day lost to this already I'm reworking the question a bit to help focus:
The overall goal is to have a bash based "server" that, using either socat (preferred) or ncat (should work well also), receives connections from one or more "clients", processes data from the clients and, when appropriate, returns a response to clients. This script also needs to be able to handle a few sundry "system management" tasks that relate to all this, and this is only mentioned because redirecting the scripts in and out would be problematic.
The overall, quite persistent problem is getting bidirectional data flow to and from the clients and this bash script simultaneously. One or the other at any one time appears to be relatively easy, but both at the same time I have not achieved yet, and when I do, this question is solved.
Early Research:
This question seems to ask the right question, but it garnered no answers that would help me.
The closest I've found so far was in this answer, but it doesn't do what I want to do. That one hands both / all IO to the connecting client, thus making it the server... What I like about it is that it actually DOES set up ncat's input and output in a useful way. Thus, the ideas contained therein were interesting enough to try and I did. However, they use a pipe for input and an > based redirect of output and in retrospect perhaps I should pursue this strategy a bit more.
However, I also tried this answer which also seems very promising, but also doesn't work.
In the comments and proposed answer it became clear that there's confusion over the terms stdin and stdout, mistaking these to mean stdin and stdout of the bash script itself. It didn't help that I was using stdin to get user input from the keyboard to help show sending to clients as well as receiving.
Of course, each program has their own view of what is standard in or out and in my writing I have only ever meant stdout and stdin from the point of view of socat or ncat.
In "pseudo code," here's an example of what the finished code might look like:
while read line
do
   # ...Process line based on it's contents.
   #
   # When a response is needed, stored in a variable
   # called reply, then this might happen:

   if [ -n "$reply" ] ;
   then
      echo "$reply" > socat_stdin
   fi
done < socat_stdout

Along the way I've tried many versions of this:
while read line
do
   echo "$line"
   echo "Back at you: $line" >&3

done < $( exec 3> >(ncat -l -k $port) )

By now I've tried all manner of redirecting to socat's stdin using < and in some configurations of that it then won't start saying it doesn't have two connections specified. Obviously I haven't hit the right combination yet.
Here's where I left off last night:
#!/bin/bash
#
port=7654
inFile=/tmp/in
outFile=/tmp/out
logFile=/tmp/log
exec /bin/socat -U TCP-LISTEN:$port,fork EXEC:"tail -f $inFile" > $outFile 2>$logFile &

while read line
do
   if [ -z "$line" ] ;
   then
      echo "EMPTY LINE!"
   else
      echo "user: $line"
      echo "Back at you: $line" > "$inFile"
   fi
done < $(tail -f "$outFile")

If I could figure out how to get the exec (not EXEC!) to perform a compound command I'd like to try putting a tail -f in front of it and pipe in the responses from the server to the client(s).
In diagnosing that, lsof shows, among many other things:
socat   3588549 root    0r   CHR                1,3      0t0         4 /dev/null

...YES, it persistently has an open file descriptor to /dev/null?! I think this is a clear sign "I'm doing it wrong!" And, indeed, in this above scenario, clients are muted. Hmmm...
Any questions about this, just ask, etc... Thanks for the help...
...For now the question remains; how is this done?

In working on this I found reference in the literature to this file: /usr/share/doc/socat/mail.sh
For anyone curious about this file it points the way BUT requires TWO programs to do this, or a second iteration; it'd be GREAT to eliminate one and I'm looking to perhaps adapt Phillipe's named pipe suggestion.
Here are that file's contents - it's fairly short:
#! /bin/sh
# source: mail.sh
# Copyright Gerhard Rieger and contributors (see file CHANGES)
# Published under the GNU General Public License V.2, see file COPYING

#set -vx

# This is an example for a shell script that can be fed to socat with exec.
# Its clue is that it does not use stdin/stdout for communication with socat,
# so you may feed the mail message via stdin to the script. The message should
# contain appropriate mail headers without continuation lines.
# socat establishes the connection to the SMTP server; the script performs the
# SMTP dialog and afterwards transfers the message body to the server.
# Lines with only a dot are not permitted - use two dots as escape.
# This script supports multiline answers from server, but not much more yet.

# Usage:  cat message.txt |socat exec:"mail.sh target@domain.com",fdin=3,fdout=4 tcp:mail.relay.org:25,crlf

while [ "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
    -f) shift; mailfrom="$1"; shift;;
    *) break;;
    esac
done

rcptto="$1"
[ -z "$1" ] && rcptto="root@loopback"
#server=$(expr "$rcptto" : '[^@]*@\(.*\)')
[ -z "$mailfrom" ] && mailfrom="$USER@$(hostname)"

# this function waits for a complete server message, checks if its status
# is in the permitted range (terminates session if not), and returns.
mail_chat () {
    local cmd="$1"
    local errlevel="$2";  [ -z "$errlevel" ] && errlevel=300

    if [ "$cmd" ]; then  echo "> $cmd" >&2;  fi
    if [ -n "$cmd" ]; then echo "$cmd" >&4; fi
    while read status message <&3;
        (
            case "$status" in
            [0-9][0-9][0-9]-*) exit 0;;
            [0-9][0-9][0-9]*) exit 1;;
            *) exit 1;;
            esac
        )
    do :; done
    if [ -z "$status" ]; then  echo smtp connection failed >&2; exit;  fi
    echo "< $status $message" >&2
    if [ "$status" -ge "$errlevel" ]; then
        echo $message >&2
        echo "QUIT" >&4; exit 1
    fi
}


# expect server greeting
mail_chat
#...more calls to the mail_chat function...


In your socat scenario, there are stdin, stdout and a port, what are their relations ?

@Philippe I don't particularly care WHAT you call them, but from a bash process point of view, using as reference what would happen in a live, interactive session with socat, stdin is from the person at the keyboard, stdout come from clients (other processes who have connected to the port), and of course stderr is logging, which you didn't ask about. Of course, to be responsive, there'd be a perpetual read loop on what comes from clients - and which would be "stdout" in the interactive case, going to the screen. That would then be acted upon and responded to using socat's "stdin"

@Philippe I added something that might give you a better idea.

If you pipe input into socat, then that side is read-only.  You should therefore run socat in unidrectional mode (-U in this case, or -u if writer and reader were reversed).  I'm uncertain whether not doing so is responsible for your problem, though.

So socat read from stdin and throw what’s read to the port, and read from the port and throw what’s read to stdout. Is this understanding correct?

@JohnBollinger Tried it and YES, -u HELPED! THANKS! It's not the whole story yet: I'm doing something wrong with the from-the-bash-script-to-client part... But this is an improvement!

@Philippe Let's not get hung up on labels: the scripts output needs to be socat's input, which then goes to the port. Socat's standard out - FROM CLIENTS USING THE PORT - needs to get into the script. And the msot recent change, based on John's input, is a step in that direction - that part works now, and the client isn't failing after two write attempts.

@JohnBollinger ... I was not entirely right or entirely wrong: With the -u flag, NO, the data isn't getting into the script from clients but it IS now going into the output file?! I've got a tail -f going on in my test environ and another in the script; the latter isn't getting the data?! Must be something simple I'm doing wrong! Arg!

Did you try named pipes (mkfifo)?

@RenaudPacalet Yes, it was an aspect of one of the examples I found and tried and it's the one I said works but hands over control to whoever connects to the port! However, in modifying from there, I didn't see how that was much different than using < and > to files and since files have the benefit of leaving a footprint on disk if you want, that's where I am now. It MIGHT be I was (am!) using < and > incorrectly, though.  ... In a few minutes I'm going to start reworking the question a bit to help clarify things and will likely throw up more examples of "where I've been so far."

Just a thought: at some point you may find it more productive to write the server in a more featureful language using threads and integrated socket support; for example, Python, Ruby, Perl, etc. You will likely be able to express what you want with much less hacky code.

@nneonneo Thanks... As noted somewhere in these comments, there was already extant bash code for this task written long, long ago, before these more convenient frameworks were readily available. If I'd had any idea that moving it to ncat / socat would be so hard I'd surely have devoted the time to the already underway - but longer to write from scratch - Java effort. But, now this effort has already improved the old code and it will likely "go into production" later today or maybe over the weekend. ...This move to socat now aids the future effort by removing a client testing bottleneck.

Indeed, the socat developers provided a major clue - hard to find, though! - with their file provided with my distribution:
/usr/share/doc/socat/mail.sh

In digging in and trying it, I got it working with something like this:
ONE script, uses functions thus:
function startSocat()
{
   # ... check for free port, etc
   socat exec:"${BASH_SOURCE[0]} -SD",fdin=3,fdout=4 TCP-LISTEN:$port,fork
   # -SD indicates, "socat-daemon"
   # 
   # The above tells it to start this same code, pass it -SD and connect to it
   # using file descriptors 3 and 4 and, of course where to listen, etc.
}

function socatLoop
{
   while read line <&3;
   do
      # Process the read in line - in variable line!
   done
}

function replyToClient()
{
   echo "$@" >&4
}

And that pretty much covers all you really need do. ... I trust the reader can fairly easily figure out how to call these but to be explicit:

Any decision process that works for you can call startSocat(). Once called, we don't expect it to return control to us since socat isn't backgrounded. If you did, then, before exiting, call wait.\
Once the daemon starts, it needs to know it started and that's what the -SD flag is all about. A clever programmer can instead determine if the process is running interactively or not, etc, an exercise left to the reader. However, once it's known this is a deamon, call socatLoop.
From here, socatLoop needs to determine how to behave and when appropriate, call replyToClient, which goes to all connected clients.

Of course, if you want to orchestrate private dialogues with an individual client, that's more work on your part, but not that hard now that you know the basics!

Minor quibble -- function funcname() { combines the legacy ksh syntax funcname { and the POSIX-standard syntax funcname() { in a way that's gratuitously incompatible with both legacy ksh and POSIX sh.

@CharlesDuffy -chuckle- That's more accident of posting than anything else. I habitually declare functions  as: function fname() {, etc. and the reason is pragmatic: I can at any time find the function definition (in vi) by using either /ion  or /(, depending on what seems easier.  BTW, I SURE wasted a lot of time on this! I expected socat to behave like most other processes, but even things like named pipes failed - I kept figuring I was doing it wrong, but now I'm not so sure! ... Whatever, I've got it working! Thanks for your replying! Cheers!


My goal is to launch an instance of either socat (preferred) or ncat (should work well also) as a "server" and have both bidirectional traffic directions - stdin and stdout - processed by a bash script.

I take you to be saying that you want to use socat as a network-facing front-end for a shell script. The client connecting to socat from the network will send data that socat forwards to the script's standard input, and the script's standard output will go back to socat to be forwarded to the client.
I can think of several ways to achieve that, but the easiest to implement might be to use a coprocess.
#!/bin/bash

port=7654
logFile=/tmp/log

coproc echo_server { cat; }

/bin/socat TCP-LISTEN:$port,fork STDIO <&${echo_server[0]} >&${echo_server[1]} 2>$logFile

Alternatively, you could use socat's SYSTEM or EXEC address type to connect it to a script.  That would be easiest to do with a separate script, but not that much harder to do with just one script:
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ $1 = --server ]; then
  port=7654
  logFile=/tmp/log

  exec /bin/socat TCP-LISTEN:$port,fork EXEC:"${BASH_SOURCE[0]} --server" 2>$logFile
else
  # echo server
  cat
fi

This variation does not depend on Bash-specific shell features.

I noted "coproc" cited in other answers in my research but MY system doesn't appear to have it, which is why I ignored it. "which coproc" returns nothing. ... If it's a buitin, I've ENTIRELY missed it!

Thanks John, trying here... The first solution doesn't work and I'm not sure how to fix. It says: "line 19: 63: No such file or directory" and the line number is the one that tries to - but fails - to start socat. ... BTW: I do not require use of stdin / stdout, and would sort of prefer they didn't. But I'll take what works and learn over time. Meanwhile, please explain what coproc is trying to do here? ... AND: Why would calling exec work and not directly?! ...I'm trying to learn here as well as solve a problem! PLUS, I DO NOT GET what the if does in the second solution.

Neither solution works as given. IDK what's preventing socat from starting on the first one since I don't understand coproc - yet, I presume - but I moved on and the second one doesn't work, either: After connecting, clients report "Broken pipe."

which coproc returns nothing because coproc is a keyword in bash, like while or if, so it's part of the bash language, not a command that which would find by looking up your PATH. It was introduced in bash 4.0 so unless you have an older bash version than that you do have it - do type coproc instead of which coproc so you see you have it and then try it. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86372/133219 for more info on coproc.

@RichardT, my apologies, I wrote the wrong redirection operators for the coproc alternative.  I can't tell you why the EXEC version doesn't work for you, but I would start troubleshooting by putting the server code in a separate script, and designating that to EXEC.  You could also try SYSTEM instead of EXEC, as already mentioned in this answer.  Any way around, SYSTEM and EXEC addresses are socat's main mechanism for what you seem to be trying to do, connecting one end of a socat-mediated channel to a program.

@JohnBollinger Thanks John, apology happily accepted - GLAD for all the help / learning ... I started a new answer of my own based on socat's example (now cited in the question), but got distracted from completing it by, well, making up for lost time implementing the code I need to complete! It also uses exec, but instead of stdio, which is, as I also have noted in an update to the q, problematic; the use of fd3 and fd4 instead are a big help and what I've got going on now. ...It's disappointed the socat devs didn't find a way to do this for the calling process, given all its sophistication.

@RichardT, I think you're misunderstanding the commentary in the message you quoted.  As I read it, the point of not using stdin / stdout for communicating with socat in that case is so that those streams can be used for something else (receiving the e-mail message text), not because socat has any particular problem with using the standard streams.

@JohnBollinger (You mean CODE I cited, not "message"?) ... Oh, SURE, but I don't care WHY they wanted to do that: My solution uses one set of code that can be/is a command-line oriented system management tool as well as daemonize , and it's having stdin and stdout NOT encumbered for socat that lets one script do it all without much pain. ...If socat let us declare fds from the parent process, that'd be nice, and surely possible, they just didn't.  ...I'm not a bad bash programmer, I just have gaps. I've used it since the late 1980s, after all! I just never took it too seriously 'till recently.

Try this version :
#!/bin/bash

if test "$1" = server; then
    while read input; do
        echo "Hello $input"
    done
    exit
fi

exec {socat_in}<>  <(true)
exec {socat_out}<> >(true)

socat - EXEC:"./test.sh server" <&$socat_in >&$socat_out &

socat_pid=$!

while read -r -p "Input (Ctrl-D to quit): " line; do
    echo "User input: $line"
    echo "$line" >&$socat_in
    echo "Response from socat:"
    head -n 1 <&$socat_out
done

exec {socat_in}>&-
exec {socat_out}>&-
kill $socat_pid

Run with :
chmod +x test.sh
./test.sh


Um... how to clients connect? Oops! Did you try this? The whole reason to use socat or ncat (netcat) is to get IO from remote clients. ...The original code before I even began already was using nfs mounted files and this work is to bring that ancient code "into the the modern era" and make it far more flexible - no NFS needed, for example.  ...My current focus is trying to parse the rather arcane syntax rules of socat to find a way to specify the file descriptors of the caling script. Calling the FDs of a child script, that socat starts is a second best option...

BTW, prompting the originator of the server end was only a temporary handy feature to generate text for a reply to clients. And the first version I posted had a bug in it. But anyway, I rewrote the question; you might take a fresh look. ... And also THANK YOU for working on this problem!

@JohnBollinger  Phillippe, John, notice the update to the question with code FROM the socat development team - worth a look!
